# Line Bot; how to get user LINE ID?

Tags: api, google-apps-script, line, chatbot

i am trying to create line chatbot with several functions in it. One of the function need to know the user LINE ID (for example: ryan123) not user id (U858382312321123......). I am using google app script to create the line chatbot

is it possible to get user LINE ID using API? or is there any way to get this through line bot?

Answer (score 0):

[/profile/{userId}](https://developers.line.biz/en/reference/messaging-api/#get-profile) is the only* way you can get `displayName`

*though there endpoints to get the profile with `userId` by further specifying the [groupId](https://developers.line.biz/en/reference/messaging-api/#get-group-member-profile) or [roomId](https://developers.line.biz/en/reference/messaging-api/#get-room-member-profile)

In case your Messaging API bot is a verified or premium account, you can use a list of `userId` of followers at anytime with [followers/ids](https://developers.line.biz/en/reference/messaging-api/#get-follower-ids)

Otherwise, you need to store them upon follow, messsage, etc. events